# Sequelize nested were when the subject of the include is possibly null

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, optional-values

In my models I have a `User` which `belongsTo({ model: Company, as: 'company' })` (and conversely  `Company` `hasMany({ model: User, as: 'members' })`)

I have constructed a query as follows

```
const query = {
  where: { onboardingState: 'pending' },
  include: [
    {
      model: Company,
      where: { suspendedAt: { [Op.eq]: null } }
    }
  ]
}

const users = await User.findAll(query)
```

This works fine if the user has an associated company. But there is an edge case (admin users) where the user does not have an associated company, and in that case the `findAll` query returns `[]`

How do I structure my query to only require `company.suspendedAt == null` if the company exists, and to ignore the company where clause if the company does not exist?